# ajax request inside click function disturb execution

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Hi I have a problem with an ajax request inside an tap/ click event which doesnt work on android webview. If I run my webapp link with chrome on the device and the pc all works fine. I tried the function after I' ve deleted the ajax function and the redirecting works then in my app. Other ajax requests work fine  in the app. It looks like something inside or the ajax function is responsible for that. I use jquery mobile 1.4.5

**my webview settings in my activity:**

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);         
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
```

**snippet of my page**

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ul" id="uItem1" data-inset="true">
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $row): ?>
    <li data-icon="false" class="listitem<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <a type="button" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <h2>test</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
    <script>
        $(".listitem<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").on('tap', function() {
            var chatid = <?php echo $row['id']; ?>;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'read.php',
                data: {
                    chatid
                },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                }
            });

            window.location.href = 'chatview.php';

        });
    </script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data: { chatid }
```

is malformed should be like

```
data: { chatid: 1 }
```

Comment: That doesnt make any difference buddy. :(

Comment: Oh excuse me I made a mistake while testing. Now the click event works. Thank you!! Didn't notice that this could responsible for that.